# Turn Swift function into extension for reuse

Tags: swift

I would like to remove specific characters from a string - instead of reentering the following across various string in my application, I would like to create an extension to easily reference across the code.

How can this be turned into an extension?

```
var string = "11224B"
let removeCharacters: Set<Character> = [" ", ";", ".", "!", "/"]
string.removeAll(where: { removeCharacters.contains($0) })
print(string)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extension:

```
extension String {
    func removeCharacters(from characterSet: CharacterSet) -> String {
        let filteredString = self.unicodeScalars.filter { !characterSet.contains($0) }
        return String(String.UnicodeScalarView(filteredString))
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
var string1 = "1122 ;4B"
print(string1.removeCharacters(from: [" ", ";", ".", "!", "/"]))
```

---

Use `removeCharacters` as default parameter:

```
extension String {
    func removeCharacters(from characterSet: CharacterSet = [" ", ";", ".", "!", "/"]) -> String {
        let filteredString = self.unicodeScalars.filter { !characterSet.contains($0) }
        return String(String.UnicodeScalarView(filteredString))
    }
}

var string1 = "1122 ;4B"
print(string1.removeCharacters())
```

Comment: Can `removeCharacters` be inside the extension? It would be best if the characters to remove were not reinstated each time

Comment: Yes,  put  `removeCharacters` inside the `func`, if that's what you want.

Comment: Can you please show an example of how that would look - having an issue understanding how to provide it in the function itself. I appreciate your help

Comment: Better yet, have the function take a CharacterSet parameter with a default value of the "normal" set the OP wants. That way you don't have to specify a CharacterSet unless it's different from the normal set.

Comment: @MarkLyson Have default value for the `characterSet` parameters, as @Duncan suggested.

Comment: @DuncanC you can make the method generic and take any sequence which element is equal to the original collection in this case a String or a Substring as well.

Comment: Is it possible to also exclude all emojis as part of the array using something like this? `{!$0.properties.isEmojiPresentation}` included in the extension?

Answer (score 2):

What you need is to extend the protocol which requires you to implement removeAll(where:) method, in this case `RangeReplaceableCollection` and constrain Self to `StringProtocol`:

---

```
extension RangeReplaceableCollection where Self: StringProtocol {
    mutating func remove(characters: Set<Element>) {
        removeAll(where: characters.contains)
    }
}
```

---

```
var string = "1/1!2.2;4 B"
string.remove(characters: [" ", ";", ".", "!", "/"])
print(string)  // "11224B\n"
```

---

And the non mutating method as well but using filter instead. You just need to return `Self`:

```
extension RangeReplaceableCollection where Self: StringProtocol {
    func removing(characters: Set<Element>) -> Self {
        filter { !characters.contains($0) }
    }
}
```

---

```
let string = "1/1!2.2;4 B"
string.removing(characters: [" ", ";", ".", "!", "/"]) // "11224B\n"
```

---

You can also make your method generic and allow any sequence type which its element is equal to the collection element type:

---

```
extension RangeReplaceableCollection where Self: StringProtocol {
    mutating func remove<S: Sequence>(characters: S) where S.Element == Element {
        removeAll(where: characters.contains)
    }
    func removing<S: Sequence>(characters: S) -> Self where S.Element == Element {
        filter { !characters.contains($0) }
    }
}
```

---

```
var string = "1/1!2.2;4 B"
let characters: Set<Character> = [" ", ";", ".", "!", "/"]
string.remove(characters: characters) 
string // "11224B\n"
```

---

```
let string = "1/1!2.2;4 B"
let charactersString = " ;.!/"
string.removing(characters: charactersString) // "11224B\n"
```

Comment: Leo, is it possible to remove all emoji as well? How can isEmojiPresentation be added into the array of characters to remove?

Comment: @MarkLyson just filter them `filter { $0.unicodeScalars.first?.properties.isEmojiPresentation == false }` if you want to remove the characters at the sequence as well as any character that isEmojiPresentation `filter { !characters.contains($0) && $0.unicodeScalars.first?.properties.isEmojiPresentation == false }`